# Meteor and iron-router: dynamically specify a template?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Every example that I have seen with iron-router specifies the template name with a string.  Is it possible to do this with a variable?  Suppose you have several routes that all use the same dynamic path, and the same data function, but they all need different templates.  Is there a way to do this without specifying a different route for every template (which would also mean changing the path I use)?

Comment: I think the way this is currently done is to add an `action` callback for your route/controller and then call `this.render` with the name of the template. Give that a try. If you can't get it to work, or this doesn't make sense, try adding a very simple version of your code to the question.

Comment: Yes, that does work.  That helps me understand better what the action callback is for also.  If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically specify things like the template and the layout with a custom [action function](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/DOCS.md#using-a-custom-action-function). The example below demonstrates showing a particular template if the required document is found based on an id in the route. You can use the same semantics for both routes and controllers.

```js
var postsController = RouteController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('post', this.params._id);
  },
  action: function() {
    if (Posts.findOne(this.params._id)) {
      this.layout('postsLayout');
      this.render('posts');
    } else {
      this.render('notFound');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Once 0.8.2 is released it should be trivial to do with `UI.dynamic` even without Iron-Router: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2123.